# Getting an object variable from List in C#

Tags: java, c#, list, variables, get

I have class with variables:

```
public class Items {
    public string name;
    public string ID;
}
```

and I have second class when I have List of object of first class

```
public class MyClass {
    public Items cheese;
    public List <Items> listOfItems = new List ();
    listOfItems.Add (cheese); // I know it should be in method or something but it's just an example
}
```

and I want get the name of the cheese, but using my list, because I have above 20 items in my list.
In Java I can do it like:

```
listOfItems.get(1).name; // 1 is an index
```

How can I do it in C#?
// Please don't try to improve my

Comment: `listOfItems[1].name`

Comment: In the example above 1 is Index Out Of Range

Comment: @KhanhTO has the right syntax, but in this example there is only one item in the list, so you'd want `listOfItems[0].name`.

Comment: For future reference, you might want to check the documentation for [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) before asking a question. There are some examples at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listOfItems[0].name;
```

Just remember to start counting at 0 ;)

Other than that its works the same way as java, just slightly different syntax

Comment: Ok, sorry last time I tried that it didn't work, now it's work and I don't know what I did wrong last time, maybe I put '.' in the [], but thx you :)

Comment: @Konowy glad to hear it :) feel free to accept one of the answers if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

The simple way:

```
listOfItems[1].name;
```

If you want a specific item try this:

```
var name = listOfItems.Find(x => x.ID == "1").name;
```

"1" is the example "Id" that you search.

Sorry for my english

I hope help you.